# Change font based on name

Tags: html, css, fonts, crystal-reports

It it possible to change every font on my website from Arial to Helvetica. Possibly with some CSS?

For instance:

```
@font-family Arial {
    Font-Family: Helvetica;
}
```

The underlying issue here is that I use 3 of 9 Barcode in some Crystal Reports. When the Crystal Report is rendered on my website it puts the css as:

```
.fc777652be-5d67-4a20-8145-dac554a82a54-4 {
    font-size: 28pt;
    color: #000000;
    font-family: 3 of 9 Barcode;
    font-weight: normal;
}
```

In Google Chrome the font doesn't want to work because it needs single quotes around the `Font-Family`.

So I'd like to find all `3 of 9 Barcode` and change to `'3 of 9 Barcode'`

Comment: Short of opening the CSS file and... making the change yourself, you'll need to use JavaScript to change all these instances, since I assume each element will have some random class name per the example above.

Comment: I cannot. The CSS is generated dynamically so there's no CSS I can just change. And the class is random each time. But I will try your js approach. Thank you!

Comment: What is causing the quotes to be missing in the first place? I mean, nobody in their right mind would assume a font name like `3 of 9 Barcode` would be OK without quotes.

Comment: @Mr Lister It's the way Crystal Report is rendering on the webpage. I am picking the font `3 of 9 Barcode`. But when I load that report to a `CrystalReportViewer` it generates it as `font-family: 3 of 9 Barcode;` which works in IE but not Chrome...

Comment: It doesn't work in Mozilla either. Font names with numbers in them can't be used safely without quote marks, so this is a bug in Crystal Reports. (Note, it's the digits, not the spaces that are the problem; things like `font-family:Times New Roman;` work fine. But numbers throw the CSS parser off.)

Answer (score 0):

You could possibly try using the global star selector.

```
* { font-family: '3 of 9 Barcode'; }
```

That would change the font of everything on the page to 3 of 9 Barcode. Of course it would be overwritten by your element's font-family if your element's selector is further down the page with the same level of specificity. Alternatively you could use the css `!important` declaration as such

```
* { font-family: '3 of 9 Barcode' !important; }
```

Beware that using !important is considered bad practice unless it's 100% necessary, in this case it would overwrite all fonts on the page and make them unchangeable (unless you used !important again).

One last thing you could try, if you have your entire report nested inside a specific div, or any other parent element, you could give that element a class.

```
<div class="report-container">

   Report . . .

</div>
```

And then you could use the star selector following the descendant selector to only select everything within that div and change the font.

```
.report-container * { font-family: '3 of 9 Barcode'; }
```

If none of those solutions would work for your needs then I believe the only other option would be to use javascript to search through all of your nodes, looking for anything with the 3 of 9 Barcode font, and setting your style to the desired font.

Comment: The best I can do is add a class on the end so it ends up being `<span class="fc85398a77-b3c5-48aa-89f5-c00245a198fb-4 report-container">*Q15*</span>` and I added the css to my main css file but it still refuses to add the css. I even tried `.report-container * { font-family: '3 of 9 Barcode' !important; }` Do you have an example of JS?

Comment: I could write up a script, but before I do that can you tell me where you are loading your font? If using !important didn't do anything then it may mean that the font itself is not being loaded into the page

Comment: you may use !important, risky but could be helpfull here instead javascript

Comment: That's the thing though, he said that using !important didn't do anything, which leads me to believe that it's an issue with the font not loading, not the syntax.

Comment: @AustinFish As mentioned above I select the Font from a drop down in Crystal Reports but when I load the report in an aspx page it assigns it a random class name with the style `font-family: 3 of 9 Barcode` so I am assuming it's doing some javascript somewhere to dynamically load in the correct styles, or in this case the wrong style...

Comment: Ok, it seems like font isn't being loaded properly, so try this for me, download the 3 of 9 Barcode font, put it in the same folder as your css document (if it generates inline css then just put it in that same folder as your page), then add this to the very top of your css `@font-face{ font-family: 3 of 9 Barcode; src: url(filename); }` replacing `filename` with whatever the font is called i.e. 3of9barcode.ttf.